# Ordering the rows of a database table

Tags: mysql, json, database-design

I have a table *feeds* that contains a collection of code-description rows.
e.g.

```
Key | Value      | Url                    
fb  | facebook   | http://www.facebook.com
tw  | twitter    | http://twitter.com     
ff  | friendfeed | http://friendfeed.com
```

A REST endpoint returns the contents of this table as a JSON array & it is displayed in a drop down box of a web page.

Today the boss wants the contents to be sorted in a specific manner.
And I would like you to comment on my designs.

**Design 1**

I add a separate column into *feeds* called rank to denote the order of the item.

```
Key | Value      | Url                     | Rank
fb  | facebook   | http://www.facebook.com | 3
tw  | twitter    | http://twitter.com      | 1
ff  | friendfeed | http://friendfeed.com   | 2
```

**Design 2**

I create a separate table *FeedRank* that stores the rank.

```
Key | Rank
fb  | 3
tw  | 1
ff  | 2
```

**Analysis**

I am leaning towards design #1 because I can dispense with the JOIN. What are the pros and cons of each design & which one would you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a one-to-one relationship, there's no real reason to put it in a separate table. Go with #1, imo.

Answer (score 3):

the only reason to put the rankings in a separate table are if either a) the relationship between the code-descriptions and the rankings was not 1:1 or if b) the column was sparsely populated (most of the rows having a NULL value)

even in the latter case most people would de-normalize and place the ranking column in the code-descriptions table.

Answer (score 0):

Design 1 is just fine.  Design 2 is essentially the same as design 1 but with unnecessary complexity.